# Importing library in Java

Tags: java

I am new in Java and learning it by a book called "Thinking in Java". Author wrote one library called `net`  to ease understanding. For example, `print` in place of `System.out.println` and likewise. So, how can I import this library?

UPDATE:
Author in his example does the following:

```
import static net.mindview.util.Range.*;
import static net.mindview.util.Print.*;
```

And I looked at his source codes and found `build.xml` in `net` folder

Comment: It is in java.lang.* package. You need not to import.

Comment: I'm not sure its wise to learn the author's (inner platform effect?) sudo programming language. (The question of how to import a library is a perfectly fair one though)

Comment: You mean `print` equals `printer`!! where do you want to print? and using which library?

Comment: @nurareum are you using Eclipse or just a simple text editor like the wordpad or VI to write your code?

Comment: @MasudCSECUET It is not. Only `System.out.println("some string");` is. If he wants to do `print("some string);`, he probably needs some import statement like e.g. `import static the.library.package.TheClassWithPrintMethod.print;`.

Comment: @morgano, I am using simple text editor. Author has written his own library called net.mindview. I cannot import this library

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically, to compile your project with an externally provided library, you should add it to the classpath. There are multiple ways to do it based on what tools you are using. If you go the "rough" way using text editor and `javac` (recommended for beginners), you can do it like this:

```
javac -classpath .:/path/to/the/folder/containing/your/library MyClass.java
```

In your case if the folder `net` is in the folder `D:\libraries` your compilation command will look like this:

```
javac -classpath .:D:\libraries MyClass.java
```

Then in your source code you can just import the library the way the author does, i.e. just copy past his code:

```
import static net.mindview.util.Range.*;
import static net.mindview.util.Print.*;

public class MyClass {
.....
}
```

If you use an IDE (for example NetBeans) you just add the library to the project. Just right-click on the `Libraries` in the `Projects Window` and choose `Add JAR/Folder`, then navigate to the folder containing the `net` library (folder `D:\libraries` in my previous example). Then the IDE will automatically add it to the classpath during the compilation.

P.S. if you are a beginner in programming, I would recommend you avoiding Thinking in Java - it is meant for people wishing to broaden their knowledge at the post-beginner level. Start with something like [Java: How to Program by Deitel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132575663) - it is written for beginners and does not use author-developed libraries confusing you as a beginner and hiding important language details from you.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple to import any library that is referenced in the Project properties. Add library in the project using properties then import that. But `net` it built-in  library provided in JDK and JRE. You can use `import java.net.*;` to use classes in the net package.